# What does $\asymp$ with regards to improper integrals?

Tags: real-analysis, notation, asymptotics, improper-integrals

I am studying improper integrals as part of a project and have come across this sign: $\asymp$. I was wondering what it meant and why it means:
$$\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=L$$
Any clarification would be greatly appreciation.